# Locking and unlocking files using C API in Ubuntu LInux

Tags: c, linux, file-io, ubuntu

How can I lock a file for a specified period of time (10 seconds) using the C language in Ubuntu Linux ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works like this:

```
#include <io.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
...
int f = open ("filename", O_RDONLY);
if (f < 0)
       error();
if (flock (f, LOCK_EX))
       error();
sleep (10);

if (flock (f, LOCK_UN))
       error();
...
```

Comment: Keep in mind that these are not mandatory locks they're advisory locks  - meaning everyone that uses the file need to flock it too. If they don't they're free to manipulate the file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fcntl(2)` to lock the file, then use `alarm(2)` to call your `SIGALRM` handler which will then unlock it.

Comment: Is it safe to call `flock` in a signal handler?

Comment: Hrm. `signal(7)` says no. `fcntl(2)` should be fine though.